# Prevent click event to fire when clicked within element, including any and all of its children elements

Tags: jquery, events, children

I have a script which opens and closes a fixed element. There's an overlay where's black background (like facebook when clicking on video) and when user clicks anywhere on the black, the overlay will be closed. But, if user clicks on the inner container, or any of elements should stay open.

My script closes the inner container if I click on any children. How to prevent this?

```
docu = $(document),
quot = $('.quote'),
quot_over = $('.quote_overlay'),
quot_cont = $('.quote_container');

quot.click(function(event) {
    quot_over.toggle(1, function() {
        docu.click(function(event) {
            var target = $(event.target);

            if(!target.is(quot_cont)) {
                quot_over.hide();

                docu.unbind('click');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: One question: how does your markup look like? Would be good to know how the elements are nested relatively to each other to understand how the click event is propagated. p/s: It is also not really a good idea to nest event handlers in another event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you have this line in there:

`quot_over.toggle(1, function()`

But that closes it immediately before it evaluates where the click was, so you need to remove that.

Secondly, you are only checking if the click is on `quote_container`, and not checking if it is on any of `quote_container`'s children.

Working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dsnosw5p/4/